# Pokemon API, Promises javascript get data inside of array json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have been working to make a small app to get the images and info from the pokemon api at http://pokeapi.co/ , I am following  course using promises however I can get a group (example: water type) which give me 78 objects , each one with a resource_uri which is the data which give me the information of each pokemon. 
Until now I have make this and I can get all the objects, however, now how can I make in order to get for each object push in the console.log (or later use them) all the 78pokemons with the data of each.
My code until now is this>

```
var $ = window.jQuery
var base = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/egg/'
Promise.resolve($.get(base + '2'))
  .then((results) =>
.then((results) => {
  var pokechara = results.pokemon
  var basechara = 'http://pokeapi.co'
  var promises = []
  for (let chara of pokechara){
    var pokech = pokechara[i]
'${something}'
    var pokechurl = basechara + pokechara[0].resource_uri
    promises.push(Promise.resolve($.get(pokechurl)))
  }
  debugger
  return Promise.all(promises)
})
.then((poke) => {
    console.log(poke)
})
.catch((err) => {
  debugger
})
```

I really wanted to make something with the api of yugioh.wikia but I dont see how I can get work because the problem with the Cros-server or header. To see a preview of what I am doing you can see at http://www.kengreg.com/yugiohapp/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please include better example code?  This is invalid javascript and won't do anything except throw errors.

Comment: hi sorry for the that, I was working on it , but this is the working code, just need jquery:
var $ = window.jQuery
var base = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/egg/'
Promise.resolve($.get(base + '2'))
.then((results) => {
  var pokechara = results.pokemon
  var basechara = 'http://pokeapi.co'
  var promises = []
  for (var i in pokechara){
    var pokech = pokechara[i]

    var pokechurl = basechara + pokechara[0].resource_uri
    promises.push(Promise.resolve($.get(pokechurl)))
  }
  debugger
  return Promise.all(promises)
})
.then((poke) => {
    console.log(poke)
})
.catch((err) => {
  debugger
})

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the code used in your reply to Alex, the string variables you use to call the api are the only thing wrong, the 'http://' part at the start is needed. Apart from that, your code works fine.

```
var $ = window.jQuery;
var base = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/egg/';
Promise.resolve($.get(base + '2'))
    .then((results) => { 
        var pokechara = results.pokemon;
        var basechara = 'http://pokeapi.co/'; 
        var promises = [];
        for (var i in pokechara){ 
            var pokech = pokechara[i]; 
            var pokechurl = basechara + pokechara[0].resource_uri;
            promises.push(Promise.resolve($.get(pokechurl)));
        } 
        debugger 
        return Promise.all(promises); 
    }) 
    .then((poke) => { 
        debugger;
        console.log(poke); 
    }) 
    .catch((err) => { debugger })
```

I left the debugger so you can checkout the results of the promises. The poke variable at the end should have the objects array you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it seems that I only get the array of the group. all the promises are objects of the group called "water". The goal that I want to do is to get the data from each of the objects from that array. In that array there are 78 objects, each one with name and resource_uri, I want to list and get the resource uri of each so I can get later the image (sprite ) of each. how can accomplish that?